# How to check for a tag in an XML File without using DOM in C / C++ (Windows)?

Tags: c++, windows, xml-parsing, tags

I want to read the XML files in the **system32\Tasks** folder and check if the   tags exist in a file or not. 
I only need to **check for a tag** in the XML file.
And the file doesn't necessarily have to be in the same directory as the project file.
    void listdirs(WCHAR *dir, WCHAR *mask)
    {
    WCHAR                   fspec1[1000], fname[1000];
    WIN32_FIND_DATAW        dta = {0};
    HANDLE                  hDta = NULL;
    DWORD                   dLastError = 0;
    LPCWSTR                 fspec = NULL;

```
swprintf(fspec1, 100, L"%ws%ws", dir, mask);
fspec = reinterpret_cast<LPCWSTR>(fspec1);

if ((hDta = FindFirstFileW(fspec, &dta)) == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {

    dLastError = GetLastError();
  printf("The error : %s\n", strerror(dLastError));



}
else {
    do {


        if ((dta.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY))
        {   
if(wcscmp(dta.cFileName, L".") !=0 &&  wcscmp(dta.cFileName, L"..") != 0)
   {    
      //Insert code snippet here to check whether the file has <Date> tag        
          or not
swprintf(fname, 100,  L"%ws%ws%ws", dir, dta.cFileName, L"\\");

listdirs(fname, mask);
}
}
else
{
            count++;
            printf("%ws\n", dta.cFileName);
            printf("Count is : %d\n", count);
}
    } while (FindNextFileW(hDta, &dta));

    FindClose(hDta);
}
}
```

I tried using TinyXml but I'm having a hard time understanding it as I have no knowledge of DOM's and would prefer an easier alternative

Comment: Here I googled it for you: http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxmldocs/tutorial0.html

Comment: @rustyx Is there a way of parsing XML files without TinyXML?

Answer (score 0):

If you are **only checking tag**, you can use RegEx:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

bool TagExists(const std::string& input,const std::string& tag)
{
    std::regex rgx(std::format("<{}>", tag));
    std::smatch match;

    if (std::regex_search(input.begin(), input.end(), match, rgx))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

But don't forget that, this doesn't control if the XML is valid or if the tag is closed. It only checks with regex.

If I inject this into your code it would be something like that:

```
swprintf(fspec1, 100, L"%ws%ws", dir, mask);
fspec = reinterpret_cast<LPCWSTR>(fspec1);

if ((hDta = FindFirstFileW(fspec, &dta)) == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {

    dLastError = GetLastError();
  printf("The error : %s\n", strerror(dLastError));



}
else {
    do {


        if ((dta.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY))
        {   
if(wcscmp(dta.cFileName, L".") !=0 &&  wcscmp(dta.cFileName, L"..") != 0)
   {    
      //Insert code snippet here to check whether the file has <Date> tag        
          or not
     
      swprintf(fname, 100,  L"%ws%ws%ws", dir, dta.cFileName, L"\\");
      listdirs(fname, mask);
    
      std::ifstream t(fname);
      std::string str((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(t)),
                 std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
      bool st=TagExists(str, "Date");
      // make whatever you want with this information. I just printed
      printf("Tag \"Date\" is %s exists in %ws\n", st? "":"not", dta.cFileName);
   }
}
else
{
            count++;
            printf("%ws\n", dta.cFileName);
            printf("Count is : %d\n", count);
}
    } while (FindNextFileW(hDta, &dta));

    FindClose(hDta);
}
}
```